# will it change .aspx.cs file to take data from html element after converting asp controls into html?

Tags: asp.net

my question was that when I send the request to the web server, of course, the web server will take the request and give me a page that will be in the HTML format so I want to know when the web server will execute asp server-side controls into HTML format than in the Testing. aspx.cs file will be changed as well? it means these two lines int no1 = Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text);
int no2 = Convert.ToInt32(textbox2.Text);

these two lines will be converted into like this int no1=Convert.ToInt32(Response["textbox1"]);
int no1=Convert.ToInt32(Response["textbox2"]); these two lines will be converted like this or not

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Testing.aspx.cs" Inherits="login.Testing" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="background-image:url(C:\Users\Sudarshan\source\repos\login\login\Images\uWjEogFLUTBc8mSvagdiuP.jpg)">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
           <table align="center">

               <tr>
                   <td>
                       Enter the Number 1:<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       Enter the Number 2:<asp:TextBox ID="textbox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       <center>
                           <br />
                           <br />
                           <asp:Button ID="button1" runat ="server" Text="Add" Height="38px" OnClick="Unnamed1_Click" Width="101px" />&nbsp;</center>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               
           </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
--------------------------------------------------------------
Testing.aspx.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System. Linq;
using System. Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web. UI.WebControls;

namespace login
{
    public partial class Testing: System.Web. UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
      

         
        }

        protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int no1 = Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text);
            int no2 = Convert.ToInt32(textbox2.Text);
            int result;
            result = no1 + no2;
            Response.Write(result);
        }
    }
```

}